# Does `top` account for all CPU usage?

Tags: top, cpu-usage, ipsec

Does the linux `top` command account for all CPU time used by the system?

I'm trying to understand bottlenecks for IPsec processing on a linux system.  In a particular case in point, the system is a VM in AWS, and we're testing IPsec throughput.  We understand the per-flow limits imposed by AWS and are not hitting that.  According to `ethtool` there is no hardware offloading for IPsec.  Without IPsec we can reach significantly higher throughput (we hit the limits advertised by AWS for the instance type.)  With IPsec the throughput is significantly lower, which is understandable, but we want to know exactly what is causing the limit.

So, I would expect that for IPsec, throughtput is limited by CPU usage (including memory wait) on the VM.  In the case I was testing we had 32 vCPUs and even with more than 32 flows, using `top` and then pressing `1` to get the per-vCPU output, none of the vCPUs were at very high utilization; most were over 50% idle.

A teammate suggested that perhaps `top` doesn't count all vCPU usage, perhaps ignoring some "core" linux kernal CPU usage.  Is this possible?

Incidentally, we see higher throughputs as number of flows increases, up to 512 (the maximum without changing ulimit.)  We also see higher throughputs as the number of IPsec tunnels increases, more than that for increasing the number of flows.  This implies to me that perhaps an `ip xfrm` state is bound to a vCPU -- but we don't see any clear evidence of that in `top` results, since none of the CPUs hits very high usage.  Most of the usage is in the `si` (software interrupt) column.

Comment: Sadly, I'm still as confused as you how "load" is defined precisely under SMP Linux with variable clock rates and heterogenous cores, but that's probably less interesting than *where your performance went*, right? I often run `sudo perf top -a` (or `sudo perf record -a; perf report`) to get a feeling for how much time is spent where - including on the kernel side (assuming you have debug symbols for your kernel). The fact that more flows leads to higher throughput would suggest that per-flow processing is essentially bound to a single core.

Comment: Actually, `load` is just the length of the queue of process waiting for CPU time, so it's straightforward.  But the CPU measurements are more complicated.  See for example, https://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-05-09/cpu-utilization-is-wrong.html .  But the issues there all work the opposite way, making CPU utillization appear higher than it really is.

Comment: *Some* of the per-flow processing is per vCPU, which is clear when showing results for few flows and watching as the number of flows increases.  But even when the number of flows exceeds the number of vCPUs, increasing the number of flows increases throughput (but not nearly proportionately.)  Increasing the number of IPsec tunnels also increases (much more so, but again not proportionately.)  So, the vCPU binding isn't clear.